# combine 3 queries in one

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, transform

I have 3 queries:

- the first one calculate Totals per Qtr and
- the other two calculate Totals per Qtr where Receipt Field is [Yes] or [No].

Now I have(example):

```
 qtrTotals
 Year / Total / TotalQtr1 / TotalQtr2 / etc...

 qtrTotalsReceiptYes
 Year / TotalYes / TotalYesQtr1 / TotalYesQtr2 / etc...

 qtrTotalsReceiptNo
 Year / TotalNo / TotalNoQtr1 / TotalNoQtr2 / etc...
```

Is it possible to make one query?

```
qtrTotals
Year / Total / TotalYes / TotalNo / TotalQtr1 / TotalYesQtr1 / TotalNoQtr1 / etc...
```

MySQL :

All:

```
 TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([price]) Is Null,0,Sum([price])) AS SumPrice
 SELECT Format([ExpencesDate],"yyyy") AS [Year], IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalPricePerYear
 FROM tblExpences
 GROUP BY Format([ExpencesDate],"yyyy")
 ORDER BY Format([ExpencesDate],"yyyy") DESC 
 PIVOT Month([ExpencesDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

Yes:

```
 TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([price]) Is Null,0,Sum([price])) AS SumPrice
 SELECT Format([ExpencesDate],"yyyy") AS [Year], IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalPricePerYear
 FROM tblExpences
 WHERE (((tblExpences.ReceiptYesNo)="Yes"))
 GROUP BY Format([ExpencesDate],"yyyy")
 ORDER BY Format([ExpencesDate],"yyyy") DESC 
 PIVOT Month([ExpencesDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

No:

```
 TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([price]) Is Null,0,Sum([price])) AS SumPrice
 SELECT Format([ExpencesDate],"yyyy") AS [Year], IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalPricePerYear
 FROM tblExpences
 WHERE (((tblExpences.ReceiptYesNo)="No"))
 GROUP BY Format([ExpencesDate],"yyyy")
 ORDER BY Format([ExpencesDate],"yyyy") DESC 
 PIVOT Month([ExpencesDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

Thank you.

PS.

The tblExpences (Correct Expenses) has [Date] / [Price] / [ReceiptYesNo].

tblExpences

```
 10/3/2017  /  200  /  Yes
 10/3/2017  /  200  /  No
 11/3/2017  /  100  /  Yes
 14/3/2017  /  100  /  No
 15/4/2017  /  200  /  Yes
 10/5/2017  /  200  /  No
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Here is a general form how you can make it work.

```
Select *
From (Query1) as Q1
Join (Query2) as Q2 On 1
Join (Query3) as Q3 On 1;
```

It should work because the 3 queries are using an aggregation function only thus returning a single row. Therefore, always joining these columns will result in each column joining and forming a single row of multiple columns.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am getting error "TRANSFORM". The only different is the Where condition.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind your queries and the output you say they give don't agree with each other. It seems like you must do something to combine your months into quarters.

Anyway, in similar style to your second and third queries:

```
TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([Price]) Is Null,0,Sum([Price])) AS SumPrice
SELECT Year([ExpensesDate]) AS [Year]
FROM tblExpenses, Numbers
WHERE (((Numbers.Number) Between 1 And 4))
GROUP BY Year([ExpensesDate])
PIVOT IIf([Number]=1,"TotalMonth"& [ReceiptYesNo] & Month([ExpensesDate]),IIf([Number]=2,"TotalMonth" & Month([ExpensesDate]),IIf([Number]=3,"TotalPerYear" & [ReceiptYesNo],"TotalPerYear"))) in ("TotalPerYear","TotalPerYearYes","TotalPerYearNo","TotalMonth1","TotalMonthYes1","TotalMonthNo1","TotalMonth2","TotalMonthYes2","TotalMonthNo2","TotalMonth3","TotalMonthYes3","TotalMonthNo3","TotalMonth4","TotalMonthYes4","TotalMonthNo4","TotalMonth5","TotalMonthYes5","TotalMonthNo5","TotalMonth6","TotalMonthYes6","TotalMonthNo6","TotalMonth7","TotalMonthYes7","TotalMonthNo7","TotalMonth8","TotalMonthYes8","TotalMonthNo8","TotalMonth9","TotalMonthYes9","TotalMonthNo9","TotalMonth10","TotalMonthYes10","TotalMonthNo10","TotalMonth11","TotalMonthYes11","TotalMonthNo11","TotalMonth12","TotalMonthYes12","TotalMonthNo12");
```

I found I had to paste this into a new query as it kept remembering old sort orders for the column headings.

This depends on a new table called `Numbers`. This needs just a single field called `Number` and should be populated with (at least) four rows of data holding the numbers: 1, 2, 3 and 4. Like this:

```
Table: Numbers

Number
------
1
2
3
4
```

**NB**: I corrected the spelling of 'Expense', which will mean you either need to tweak your data or my query so they agree.

Comment: Do let me know how you get on with this.

Comment: Thank you Steve, but I need to combine the 3 queries in one. The tblExpences (Correct Expenses) has      [Date] / [Price] / [ReceiptYesNo]. I need one query with the output      [Year] / [TotalPerYear] / [TotalPerYearYes] / [TotalPerYearNo] / [TotalMonth1] / [TotalMonthYes1] / [TotalMonthNo1] / ...etc for the rest months.

Comment: Did you try it? If not, you may be surprised.

Comment: If you see my queries the only different is the lines WHERE CONDITION in the 2 and 3. All the other sql is the same.

Comment: Yes, you separate out the Yes/No/Totals. I do that too, but without where clause, just grouping.

Comment: ok. but how can I add the sum inside the fields? SumYes and SumNo

Comment: I'm not sure i understand.

Comment: I need to see the sums of Total / Yes / No. You break the fields but how can I see the sums? I only see the sum of the All Totals.

Comment: There should be 40 columns in the results from my code: 1 x Year, 3 x YearTotals, 3 x 12 = 36 Month Totals. Are these not what you need?

Comment: Perhaps it's the column headings I've used that are confusing.

Comment: I've edited my answer to change the column headings to agree with those you suggested in your first response here.

Comment: The problem is that I now I have the columns but with no values. It must have the Sum of each Month (Total, TotalYes, TotalNo).

Comment: Each Month have a TotalYes and TotalNo. Both of them, is Total. My problem is how to Sum this Totals

Comment: Did you change just the `in` part, or the whole `PIVOT` line? You need to do the latter.

Comment: My question was to combine 3queries in 1. I had one query for Totals, one for TotalYes and one for TotalNo.

Comment: Let's go another route. I'll be back with a second answer shortly, though I think this one is actually fine.

Comment: No I leave it as is

Comment: Check my first question down. See how the table look like.

Comment: TotalYes + TotalNo = Total.  Hope this help

Comment: So in my table above. I have on (3) Month => 300 + 300 = 600. On (4) Month => 200 + 0 = 200. On (5) Month => 0 + 200 = 200.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a different approach. Firstly, I've assumed your three queries are saved as: `qryTotalTotal`, `qryTotalYes`, `qryTotalNo`.

```
SELECT qryTotalTotal.Year,
qryTotalTotal.TotalPricePerYear AS TotalPerYear,
qryTotalYes.TotalPricePerYear AS TotalPerYearYes,
qryTotalNo.TotalPricePerYear AS TotalPerYearNo,
qryTotalYes.[1]+qryTotalNo.[1] as TotalMonth1,
qryTotalYes.[1] as TotalMonthYes1,
qryTotalNo.[1] as TotalMonthNo1,
qryTotalYes.[2]+qryTotalNo.[2] as TotalMonth2,
qryTotalYes.[2] as TotalMonthYes2,
qryTotalNo.[2] as TotalMonthNo2,
qryTotalYes.[3]+qryTotalNo.[3] as TotalMonth3,
qryTotalYes.[3] as TotalMonthYes3,
qryTotalNo.[3] as TotalMonthNo3,
qryTotalYes.[4]+qryTotalNo.[4] as TotalMonth4,
qryTotalYes.[4] as TotalMonthYes4,
qryTotalNo.[4] as TotalMonthNo4,
qryTotalYes.[5]+qryTotalNo.[5] as TotalMonth5,
qryTotalYes.[5] as TotalMonthYes5,
qryTotalNo.[5] as TotalMonthNo5,
qryTotalYes.[6]+qryTotalNo.[6] as TotalMonth6,
qryTotalYes.[6] as TotalMonthYes6,
qryTotalNo.[6] as TotalMonthNo6,
qryTotalYes.[7]+qryTotalNo.[7] as TotalMonth7,
qryTotalYes.[7] as TotalMonthYes7,
qryTotalNo.[7] as TotalMonthNo7,
qryTotalYes.[8]+qryTotalNo.[8] as TotalMonth8,
qryTotalYes.[8] as TotalMonthYes8,
qryTotalNo.[8] as TotalMonthNo8,
qryTotalYes.[9]+qryTotalNo.[9] as TotalMonth9,
qryTotalYes.[9] as TotalMonthYes9,
qryTotalNo.[9] as TotalMonthNo9,
qryTotalYes.[10]+qryTotalNo.[10] as TotalMonth10,
qryTotalYes.[10] as TotalMonthYes10,
qryTotalNo.[10] as TotalMonthNo10,
qryTotalYes.[11]+qryTotalNo.[11] as TotalMonth11,
qryTotalYes.[11] as TotalMonthYes11,
qryTotalNo.[11] as TotalMonthNo11,
qryTotalYes.[12]+qryTotalNo.[12] as TotalMonth12,
qryTotalYes.[12] as TotalMonthYes12,
qryTotalNo.[12] as TotalMonthNo12
FROM (qryTotalTotal LEFT JOIN qryTotalYes ON qryTotalTotal.Year = qryTotalYes.Year)
LEFT JOIN qryTotalNo ON qryTotalTotal.Year = qryTotalNo.Year;
```